# PHP Print on HTML Design

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP code and I want to put the successful print (instead of a new white page) into my design in the html part of that php file:

PHP

```
<?php

    // GET EMAIL
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    // To avoid problems, only lower case is used
    $email=strtolower($email);
    // Check whether email is correct by using a function
    //  function requires the email address and the error message
    check_email ($email, "Error: email is not valid.");

    $emails = $file;
    $count = substr_count('@', $emails);


  // GET VALUE FOR action : subc (subscribe) or unsubc (unsubscribe)
$action=$_POST["action"];

// this is the file with the info (emails)
//    When using the link in the top to download the complete script, a new  
name for this file
//    will be generated (p.e.: emaillist-2ax1fd34rfs.txt), so users will be 
unable to find it
$file = "emaillist-5g04kNwj69.txt";

// lets try to get the content of the file
if (file_exists($file)){
    // If the file is already in the server, its content is pasted to variable 
$file_content
    $file_content=file_get_contents($file);
}else{
    // If the file does not exists, lets try to create it
    //   In case file can not be created (probably due to problems with 
directory permissions),
    //   the users is informed (the first user will be the webmaster, who must 
solve the problem).
    $cf = fopen($file, "w") or die("Error: file does not exits, and it can not 
be create.<BR>Please check permissions in the directory or create a file with coresponding name.");
    fputs($cf, "Mailing list subscribers\n");
    fclose($cf);
}

 // IF REQUEST HAS BEEN TO SUBSCRIBE FROM MAILING LIST, ADD EMAIL TO THE FILE
if ($action=="subc"){
    // check whether the email is already registered
    if(strpos($file_content,"<$email>")>0){die("Error: your email is already 
included in this mailing list");}
    // write the email to the list (append it to the file)
    $cf = fopen($file, "a");
    fputs($cf, "\n<$email>");       // new email is written to the file in a 
    new line
    fclose($cf);
    // notify subscription
    print "Your email has been added to our mailing list.<br>Thanks for 
    joining us.";
    }
// IF REQUEST HAS BEEN TO UNSUBSCRIBE FROM MAILING LIST, REMOVE EMAIL FROM THE 
FILE
if ($action=="unsubc"){
    // if email is not in the list, display error
    if(strpos($file_content,"<$email>")==0){die("Error: your email is not 
included in this mailing list");}
    // remove email from the content of the file
    $file_content=preg_replace ("/\n<$email>/","",$file_content);
    // print the new content to the file
    $cf = fopen($file, "w");
    fputs($cf, $file_content);
    fclose($cf);
    // notify unsubscription
    print "Your email has been removed from our mailing list. ";
}

?>
```

and I want to insert that print instead on my html

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>TAPITAP APP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>



        <audio id="audioPromotional" src="promotional.mp3" ></audio>

        <img id="tapiLogo" src="images/logo.svg">

        <div id="tapiWrapper">
            <img id="finger" src="images/finger.svg"/>
            <img id="tapi2" src="images/img1.svg"/>
            <img id="tapi1" src="images/img2.svg"/>
            <img id="tapi1Shadow" src="images/shadow.svg"/>         
        </div>

        <div id="emailBox">

            <form action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">


                    <div id="descriptionText">
                        <h4 class="descriptionText">We’re about to launch our game app really soon!
If you subscribe we'll let you know few days before the big day!! and also the very same day the app is active on store, thanks for your help!</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div id="emailImputPositioning">
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email..."> 
                    </div>

                    <div id="responsiveTest">
                    <input type="radio" id="unsubscribe" class="rad" name="action" value="unsubc"/>
                    <label class="labelFirst" for="unsubscribe">UNSUBSCRIBE</label>
                    </div>

                    <div id="responsiveTest2">
                    <input type="radio" id="subscribe" class="rad" name="action" value="subc"/>
                    <label class="labelSecond" for="subscribe">SUBSCRIBE</label>
                    </div>



                    <button class="btn" id="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">SEND</button>

            </form>

    I WANT TO INSERT THAT PRINT HERE


    </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

That's what I would like to do, could someone help me to understand how to solve this? appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your output into a PHP variable and echo it where you need.
Instead of print use like this:.

```
 <?php
 $output= "my Output message";
 ?>
 <html>
   ....
 </form>
 <?php
 echo $output;
 ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your PHP script into a function and call the latter in your HTML where you want to display your message.